# What happens to a process running in a CPU when it goes offline

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, cpu-usage

I make certain CPUs to go offline using the command

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$cpu/online
```

Post which my `nproc`, `grep "processor" /proc/cpuinfo` and `lscpu` confirms that the CPU is offline. In such a scenario:

1. What happens to a process pinned to that CPU (is the expectation a kill / migration to another CPU ?)
2. What happens to a process that was running in that CPU (will it get migrated to another CPU?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No process is killed, that would be a disservice.
When a CPU is put offline, its tasks are migrated:

> All processes are migrated away from this outgoing CPU to new CPUs. The new CPU is chosen from each process’ current cpuset, which may be a subset of all online CPUs.

<sup>from [Official Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/cpu_hotplug.html)</sup>

This leaves open the question of tasks that were pinned to that specific CPU. You can [dig into the kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2019) to see that the fallback is to unpin those task from the offlined CPU.
Their new affinity mask is set to all the possible CPUs.